# How to force a single line formatting for tags?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to force code reformatting to format HTML (Vue, ...) tags in a single line

```
<q-btn @click="newNote()" color="green" label="new note">
```

instead of the default

```
     <q-btn
        @click="newNote()"
        color="green"
        label="new note"
      >
```

What should I modify in Setting in order to achieve that? (The entries for `Vue` formatting did not have that setting)

Comment: Set Hard wrap at under `Preferences / Settings | Editor | Code Style`.

Comment: @s0xzwasd: not sure I understand: why HardWrap? This is to ensure that long lines are wrapped (or not) but it will not help with the structure of attributes. Mine is set to `0` as an example (so that hard wraps do not happen at all - but I still have attributes reformatted)

Comment: What language is this written in? What framework are you using? What's the file extension?